# How to keep text selection visible in a text area even though not focused in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, textselection

I am making a **Speed Typing Test** script using **tkinter** just like [this website](http://10fastfingers.com). But I am stuck in making selection to the text when the focus is in another widget.

> Is it even possible to do make a selection visible in **Text** widget
> when the focus is in **Entry** widget?

Comment: Does it have to be selection, or could you just set the background color of the text to have a similar visual effect? See e.g. [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_text.htm) right at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I did it myself using tags.

Comment: If you found a solution you may consider self-answering your question.

Comment: Yeah about to do it

Answer (score 4):

You can set the `exportselection` option of the text widget to `False`. That will prevent the selected text from automatically being associated with the clipboard. It is that automatic association which causes the selection to be removed whenever focus changes.

Comment: setting `exportselection` to `False` made no difference because whenever I changed focus to another widget the selection disappears. I think whenever the focus is changed it is the automatic behavior of **Text** widget to make the selection disappear. So, I used tags which solved my problem. **Am I missing something ?**

Comment: @Ghanteyyy: I don't know. Maybe your platform defines a different color for un-focused selection. On my system the text remains highlighted, though it turns from blue to gray when the window loses focus.

Comment: I am on Windows. Is it so `exportselection` is not behaving correctly ?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out myself that adding tags solves the problem.

```
text_widget.tag_add('highlight', '1.0', '1.24')
text_widget.tag_config('highlight', background='#0078d7')
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `exportselection` to `False` and the `inactiveselect` attribute to the same color of the `selectbackground` attribute.
Example:

```py
    import tkinter as tk
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    text = tk.Text(root, exportselection = False)
    text.config(inactiveselect = text.cget("selectbackground"))
    text.pack(fill = "both", expand = True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Example using class inheritance:

```py
    import tkinter as tk
    
    class myText(tk.Text):
        def __init__(self, master, **kw):
            tk.Text.__init__(self, master = master, **kw)
            if 'exportselection' not in kw.keys():
                self['exportselection'] = False
            if 'inactiveselect' not in kw.keys():
                self['inactiveselect'] = self['selectbackground']
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    text = myText(root)
    text.pack(fill = "both", expand = True)
    root.mainloop()
```

This way the Text widget will automatically set the `exportselection` to `false` and the `inactiveselect` to `selectbackground` if you dont define any value to then.